# Can I handle exceptions in for-each loop without switching to explicit iterator?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, exception

I am using the [htsjdk SamReader](https://samtools.github.io/htsjdk/javadoc/htsjdk/htsjdk/samtools/SamReader.html) class as follows:

```
try(
    SamReader reader = SamReaderFactory.makeDefault().open(new File(filename))
){
    for(SAMRecord record : reader){ // potential exception here, based on file input
        // process record
    }
}
catch(SAMFormatException e){
    // rest of loop is skipped by handling exception here
}
```

The SamReader class basically reads from a text file, and generates a new SAMRecord from each line in the text file. The SamReader class performs checks on each line in the file and can throw a runtime SAMFormatException. I can handle this exception, but I have not discovered a way to handle it with the for-each loop while still attempting to process the remainder of the file.

Is there a way to handle the runtime exception while using the for-each loop format and continue to process the remainder of the file? Or do I need to explicitly use an iterator to get control over this?

Answer (score 1):

Put the try catch *inside* the loop

```
SamReader reader = SamReaderFactory.makeDefault().open(new File(filename));

for(SAMRecord record : reader){ 
    try {
    // process record
    } catch(SAMFormatException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Or -- as you explained the exception is thrown by while iterating -- you use a more low api way with `iterator()`

```
Iterator<SAMRecord> it = reader.iterator()
while(it.hasNext()) {
    try {
        SAMRecord record = it.next();
        // process record
    } catch(SAMFormatException e) {
        // do handling here
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work because the exception is thrown upon generating the  `SAMRecord record`, and not while processing it.

Comment: @mattm added a solution with iterator

Comment: Thanks for the solution sketch, but I am actually more interested in whether this kind of exception handling is possible with the for-each loop, or whether the iterator approach is necessary.